# Inner product space related to pythagorean theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I understand that the an inner product space basically uses pythagorean theorem because it is similar to a distance formula. I'm still having trouble with this proof. I am a bit confused about where to start. It could be notation that is throwing me off, so any breakdown would be great.

Comment: Use the fact that $\|v\|^2$ is defined as $\langle v,v\rangle$. Use also the fact that, by definition, $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal iff $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$. Start on the LHS and arrive, by a series of equalities, at the RHS.

Comment: you can select an answer as correct answer at the left side of the answer, remember do this for help the comunity.

Answer (score 2):

Let be $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ an orthogonal set, then:

$$\|\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i\|^2=\langle \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i;\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jv_j\ \rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\langle a_iv_i;a_j,v_j\rangle $$ Here almost all products will be zero because $v_i$ is orthogonal to $v_j$ iff $i\neq j$ then the non-zero terms are these where $i=j$:
$$=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle a_iv_i;a_i,v_i\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|^2\langle v_i,v_i\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|^2\|v_i\|^2$$